# Skip tests in Grails

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, integration-testing, skip

How can I skip the unit and integration tests in Grails when building? I cannot find an option...  I am not using Maven but simply `grails <myScript>`

Thanks

Jonas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you wrote a custom script? Don't invoke the TestApp script and go directly to the War script.

Comment: OK, but if I sometimes wanna run the tests and sometimes skip them, do I have to introduce my own property?

Comment: Yes. There's no magical way for the script to know if you want to run the tests or not.